# Using arrow functions as data services

Tags: reactjs

In angular you devide you code calling REST services in seperate classes/components. I am trying to do something similar in REACT. From multiple posts in here I can see it is recommended to use arrow functions over classes. Does the same apply for for REST/data services? Why I ask is I get a lot of lint warning when having code like below. All recommendation on best practices consuming REST services are welcome.

```
export const DataService = () => {
  const getCustomers = params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  };

  const getProducts = params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  };
};
```

[image]

When using the component I get following:

```
import { CrawlService } from "../../services/CrawlService";

 test() {
    CrawlService.getProducts("sdfs");
  }
```

> _services_CrawlService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__.CrawlService.getProducts
>   is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions are preferred over classes for defining React components. For anything else, you can use whatever you prefer.

The ESLint warning messages from your code examples are not caused by arrow functions per se, but by how you use them – you assign an arrow function to the constant `getCustomers`, without actually doing anything with `getCustomers`. ESLint would complain just as well if you used a regular function.

In the code example in your question, you export an arrow function, and inside its function body, you define two more arrow functions and assign them to the constants `getCustomers` and `getProducts`. Those constants, however, are only accessible in the scope of the function you are exporting:

```
export const DataService = () => {
  const getCustomers = params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  };

  const getProducts = params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  };
};
```

What I *think* you want to do is probably this:

```
export const DataService = {
  getCustomers: params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  },

  getProducts: params => {
    alert("sfdff");
  }
};
```

This way, you export not a function, but an object, which has two properties `getCustomers` and `getProducts`.

You can now use the object like in your code example:

```
import { DataService } from "../../services/DataService";

test() {
  DataService.getProducts("sdfs");
}
```

Comment: Thansks appreciated. I will answer when possible in 4 minutes. Can you tell why it fails when using the component (see main post)?

Comment: Thanks appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Patrick Hund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59736340/8186898). I think what you wanted to write was the following:

```
export const DataService = {
  getCustomers(params) {
    // ...
  },
  getProducts(params) {
    // ...
  },
};
```

Notice how you're exporting an object with two properties. You can use it like that:

```
import { DataService } from './DataService';

DataService.getProducts('xxx');
```

Comment: But then we are back to just using normal js functions? Is there any advantage one over the other? Or just using regular classes?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. There's a lot to unpack here. This could be a better for the software engineering stack exchange, or the code review one.